# angular.js resource doesn't resolve: resolved false

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use resource on a url (which exists, I doublechecked by posting it into the browser address bar). I'm using resource within a directive like this:

```
var imagesResource = $resource("/myurl");
var images = imagesResource.get();
```

problem: images stays unresolved. I've used resource before on various occasions - hasn't caused any problems so far until now. There is no error in the console which is not very helpful.

Any ideas on how to fix? I don't really want to fall back onto a jquery ajax request...

Comment: In which context is this snippet running? Controller? User event?

Comment: please post a jsfiddle and plunkr example

Comment: it's running inside a directive

Comment: Use the browser tools and see if the request to myurl is even happening and what is being returned. Also, try dropping the leading '/'.